# Delaying Navigation between screens with react navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

What I want to achieve is when a user clicks on a screen to navigate to another screen, I want the transitioning between the screens to be delayed for 1 second or 2seconds.

I don't know if this is possible in

> React navigation

.

I have this code that will transition from `home` to `profile` screen.

```
    import * as React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const MyStack = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeScreen}
          options={{ title: 'Welcome' }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name="Profile" component={ProfileScreen} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
```

And this is the `home` screen code

```
const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <Button
      title="Go to Jane's profile"
      onPress={() =>
        navigation.navigate('Profile', { name: 'Jane' })
      }
    />
  );
};
```

And this is the `profile` screen code.

```
const ProfileScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {
  return <Text>This is {route.params.name}'s profile</Text>;
};

};
```

Is possible to move from `home` screen to `profile` screen with a delay in time

Comment: You could use the setTimeout function to delay the action.

setTimeout(()=> {
    navigation.navigate('Profile', { name: 'Jane' })
},2000);

but may I ask why?. what is it that you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: That's what he client wants

Comment: Well, the setTimeout function will wait until the timeout to execute the callback function. This will solve your problem. But I don't think it is a good practice to have such a hardcoded delay in your application code.

Comment: I know and have tried to talk him out of it but he refused, insisting that that is what he wants

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @nithinpp suggested, You could achieve this by adding a `setTimeout` for 2s in the Home screen button onClick.

```js
const HomeScreen = ({ navigation }) => {
  return (
    <Button
      title="Go to Jane's profile"
      onPress={() => {
        setTimeout(()=> {
         navigation.navigate('Profile', { name: 'Jane' });
        }, 2000);
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

I don't really see a reason to use this code in any application, as this is not at all a good practice to have a hardcoded delay in your application code.